# RecyclerView not showing in Layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview, androidx

I want to achieve a layout as shown in the Android Studio preview (left). However if executed in the emulator, only the button is visible and the RecyclerView is not visible/populated (right).
[image]

The XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
style="@style/AppTheme">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:name="com.example.app.ItemFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
    tools:context=".ItemFragment"
    tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_item"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

However if the **RecyclerView is alone in the fragment the list is populated** (but of course the action button is not showing). Code see below. And yes, my list which should be shown is *not* empty.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:name="com.example.app.ItemFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
    tools:context=".ItemFragment"
    tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_item" >
</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

I have already tried using **RelativeLayout** and **FrameLayout**, but I still get the same result. The same behavior occurs if I use e.g. a TextView instead of the action button.

**--- Requested additional info ---**

Adapter class (automatically generated by Android Studio, template):

```
class MyItemRecyclerViewAdapter(
    private val mValues: List<DummyItem>,
    private val mListener: OnListFragmentInteractionListener?
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private val mOnClickListener: View.OnClickListener

    init {
        mOnClickListener = View.OnClickListener { v ->
            val item = v.tag as DummyItem
            // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the fragment is attached to
            // one) that an item has been selected.
            mListener?.onListFragmentInteraction(item)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.fragment_item, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = mValues[position]
        holder.mIdView.text = item.id
        holder.mContentView.text = item.content

        with(holder.mView) {
            tag = item
            setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = mValues.size

    inner class ViewHolder(val mView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(mView) {
        val mIdView: TextView = mView.item_number
        val mContentView: TextView = mView.content

        override fun toString(): String {
            return super.toString() + " '" + mContentView.text + "'"
        }
    }
}
```

List fragment (automatically generated by Android Studio, template):

```
class ItemFragment : Fragment() {

    // TODO: Customize parameters
    private var columnCount = 1

    private var listener: OnListFragmentInteractionListener? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        arguments?.let {
            columnCount = it.getInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_list, container, false)

        // Set the adapter
        if (view is RecyclerView) {
            with(view) {
                layoutManager = when {
                    columnCount <= 1 -> LinearLayoutManager(context)
                    else -> GridLayoutManager(context, columnCount)
                }
                adapter = MyItemRecyclerViewAdapter(DummyContent.ITEMS, listener)
            }
        }
        return view
    }

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        if (context is OnListFragmentInteractionListener) {
            listener = context
        } else {
            throw RuntimeException(context.toString() + " must implement OnListFragmentInteractionListener")
        }
    }

    override fun onDetach() {
        super.onDetach()
        listener = null
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     *
     *
     * See the Android Training lesson
     * [Communicating with Other Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)
     * for more information.
     */
    interface OnListFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        fun onListFragmentInteraction(item: DummyItem?)
    }

    companion object {

        // TODO: Customize parameter argument names
        const val ARG_COLUMN_COUNT = "column-count"

        // TODO: Customize parameter initialization
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(columnCount: Int) =
            ItemFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT, columnCount)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: show your Adapter class

Comment: I have added the adapter class to the question (I have used this sample class which is automatically created by Android Studio). However I believe that the error lies within the XML, because if I remove the ConstraintLayout and the button, the list is shown correctly.

Comment: can you please show you activity

Comment: @Amitpandey I have included the fragment which is responsible for the list (it is a sample template generated by Android Studio). The list is shown correctly if the RecyclerView is located alone in the XML, so I still believe that everything else is fine except the extra parts (ConstraintLayout + button) in the XML itself. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Where is the data set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this for your layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="@style/AppTheme"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:name="com.example.app.ItemFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:context=".ItemFragment"
        tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_item" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Inside `ItemFragment.kt` replace `onCreateView` with

```
override fun onCreateView(
inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_list, container, false)
}
```

After that go ahead and implement `onViewCreated` as such

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    with(list) {
        layoutManager = when {
            columnCount <= 1 -> LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
            else -> GridLayoutManager(requireContext(), columnCount)
        }
        adapter = MyItemRecyclerViewAdapter(DummyContent.ITEMS)
    }
}
```

This should fix your problem because the AS template is assuming that the rootview will be a `RecyclerView` and is treating the whole layout as such.

Comment: still the same issue.. the button is shown but the RecyclerView list entries are not

Comment: I just tried with the template from android studio and I have seen why you are facing your problems.

Comment: @blackst0ne I have made additions to the solution

Comment: Doesn't onCreateView have to return ViewHolder, when view holder class is an inner class?

Comment: @CyberShark in the context of a `RecyclerView.Adapter`, yes. But in the context of a Fragment, it has to return a View. `ItemFragment` is a `Fragment` and not a `RecyclerView.Adapter` that is why we inflate a view and return it.

Comment: @Rafsanjani thanks a lot for your help! doing the adjustments to ItemFragment.kt solved the issue:)